# Flutter Icons showing as white boxes

Tags: android, flutter, mobile, icons

There's some problem going on with my Flutter Icons. They were working fine before, but when i added custom fonts, all Icons started appearing as white boxed as shown below. the Icons syntax is perfect, Tried commenting new added features, Did try new icons (Nothing changes), also tried wiping emulator data, nothing helps

[image: Output]

"Pubspec.Yaml"

```yaml
name: ableease_games
description: A new Flutter project.
# The following line prevents the package from being accidentally published to
# pub.dev using `flutter pub publish`. This is preferred for private packages.
publish_to: 'none' # Remove this line if you wish to publish to pub.dev

# The following defines the version and build number for your application.
# A version number is three numbers separated by dots, like 1.2.43
# followed by an optional build number separated by a +.
# Both the version and the builder number may be overridden in flutter
# build by specifying --build-name and --build-number, respectively.
# In Android, build-name is used as versionName while build-number used as versionCode.
# Read more about Android versioning at 
https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/versioning
# In iOS, build-name is used as CFBundleShortVersionString while build-number is used as 
CFBundleVersion.
# Read more about iOS versioning at
#https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CoreFoundationKeys.html
# In Windows, build-name is used as the major, minor, and patch parts
# of the product and file versions while build-number is used as the build suffix.
version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
  sdk: '>=3.1.5 <4.0.0'

# Dependencies specify other packages that your package needs in order to work.
# To automatically upgrade your package dependencies to the latest versions
# consider running `flutter pub upgrade --major-versions`. Alternatively,
# dependencies can be manually updated by changing the version numbers below to
# the latest version available on pub.dev. To see which dependencies have newer
# versions available, run `flutter pub outdated`.
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter

  audioplayers: ^5.2.1
  smooth_page_indicator: ^1.1.0
  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.6


  # The following adds the Cupertino Icons font to your application.
  # Use with the CupertinoIcons class for iOS style icons.


dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter

  # The "flutter_lints" package below contains a set of recommended lints to
  # encourage good coding practices. The lint set provided by the package is
  # activated in the `analysis_options.yaml` file located at the root of your
  # package. See that file for information about deactivating specific lint
  # rules and activating additional ones.
  flutter_lints: ^2.0.0

# For information on the generic Dart part of this file, see the
# following page: https://dart.dev/tools/pub/pubspec

# The following section is specific to Flutter packages.
flutter:

  # The following line ensures that the Material Icons font is


  # included with your application, so that you can use the icons in
  # the material Icons class.

  # To add assets to your application, add an assets section, like this:
  assets:
  - lib/assests/images/
  - lib/assests/images/instructions/

  # An image asset can refer to one or more resolution-specific "variants", see
  # https://flutter.dev/assets-and-images/#resolution-aware

  # For details regarding adding assets from package dependencies, see
  # https://flutter.dev/assets-and-images/#from-packages

  # To add custom fonts to your application, add a fonts section here,
  # in this "flutter" section. Each entry in this list should have a
  # "family" key with the font family name, and a "fonts" key with a
  # list giving the asset and other descriptors for the font. For
  # example:
  # fonts:
  #   - family: coolvetica
  #     fonts:
  #       - asset: fonts/coolvetica-rg.otf
  #       - asset: fonts/coolvetica-condensed-rg.otf
  #         weight: 400

  #   - family: Trajan Pro
  #     fonts:
  #       - asset: fonts/TrajanPro.ttf
  #       - asset: fonts/TrajanPro_Bold.ttf
  #         weight: 700
  #
  # For details regarding fonts from package dependencies,
  # see https://flutter.dev/custom-fonts/#from-packages
```

Comment: try flutter pub cache clean and check

Comment: Please include details on how you add custom fonts

Comment: @HardikMehta Tried, Nothing changes

Comment: @DhafinRayhan 

` Icon(
                             
                            Icons.arrow_forward_ios_rounded,
                            color: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.secondary,
                            size: 18,
                            )
`

This is example of one icon used with start button

Comment: No, how did you add those custom fonts? Because in the pubspec you don't have custom fonts set

Comment: @DhafinRayhan sorry my bad, I added that "coolvetica" font, downloaded it, added the downloaded file in a 'font' folder in the project folder. then added it in pubspec. But when the icons were not showing, so i tried to comment the 'font statement' and check, but still it dont shows.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're using a Material icon (`Icons.arrow_forward_ios_rounded`) but you're missing the line that enables Material design in pubspec.yaml.

```yaml
flutter:
  uses-material-design: true
```

Comment: Thank you so much, Strange that it was working before without this line. But now it fixed my problem, thank you again!!

Answer (score 0):

Pubspec.Yaml file is white-space sensitive, by that said I think that your assets are not indent/tucked in enough.

```
` assets:
    - lib/assests/images/
    - lib/assests/images/instructions/`
```

Also check if your path is correct, you have typo "assests"?

Comment: All is good, nothing changes

Comment: did you add relative path which points to those icons below 'assets' in pubspec.yaml? If you did and if you fixed white-space mistake that you had, it should work fine

Comment: No, i dont think those icons require a path to be written. The icons i used are inbuilt in flutter.

Comment: try flutter clean and flutter upgrade